# Configuring Event Grid return using configuration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I am working on an Azure Functions PoC that can communicate with event grid.
I am trying to connect to the endpoint with a topic key and uri.

```cs
 [FunctionName("MyFunction1")]
 [return: EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "MyEventGridTopicUriSetting", TopicKeySetting = "MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")]
 public async Task<CloudEvent> Run([EventGridTrigger]CloudEvent cloudEvent)
 {
     // ...

     return new CloudEvent(
         "/myfunction1/add/",
         "Internal.EventRecorded",
         new
         {
             EventId = cloudEvent.Id,
             CorrelationId = correlationId
         }
     );
 }
```

Eventually this function will need to be deployed across multiple subscriptions so the uri and topic key attributes will change. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The strings used here in the attribute are app settings defined on your Azure Function resource.

So, the code itself would not have to change but when creating the Azure Function resource, you would set the value to depending on the subscription it's in.

This should be handled in your ARM/Bicep Templates with which you are creating the underlying resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the appsettings be as simple as:
TopicEndpointUri: ""
TopicKeySetting: ""

Comment: The string value in the attribute is the name of the app setting. For the code you've shared, you would have to create app settings with names `MyEventGridTopicUriSetting` and `MyEventGridTopicKeySetting`, and appropriate values.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'll give that a try when I can.